# Column editing with different length in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I tried Googling but didn't have success

Let's assume I have the following text opened in Notepad++

```
uyfgud
dbfg
dsb
fbfbgfsgb
sdfb
dbfgdb
dbfgdf
vbsd
bf
```

How can I add certain character to the **END** of each row? I know it is possible in sublime but out of curiosity was wondering if it is possible in Notepad++ as well. 
I tried shift+Alt to select multiple rows but I don't know how can I get the cursor to the end of each single line.

Comment: AFAIK, at end of each row at _specific column_ you can achieve this in Notepad++ too using block selection, but not at end of line where columns vary.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu select `Search` > `Replace`

For `Search Mode` select "Regular expression"

Find what: $ `<-- end of line`

Replace with: @ `<-- special character which will appear at the end of each line`

Then hit `Replace All`